# How to delete/uninstall Titan graph database

Tags: database, graph, titan

Does anyone know how to properly uninstall titan graph database. I have Titan 0.5.0 installed on my server but I want to install Titan 0.5.4 to perform testing on this version.

Can I simply delete the extracted Titan 0.5.0 folder to uninstall the previous version of titan? Or there are some commands that I need to use to do the uninstall?

I also want to know if I can have multiple versions of titan installed on the same server?

Thanks for taking a look at these questions!

Answer (score 0):

Titan doesn't "install" anything.  Simply delete the directory that you unzipped the distribution to.  If you want multiple versions of Titan present on the same server, that's not really a problem either.  Just unpackage them to different directories.